# Inserted pictures not visible

Tags: excel, vba

Fellow sufferes!

My VBA inserts pictures into cells. The pictures are avatars from Atlassian Confluence, so quite small. They used to be visible, but suddenly they start being somehow hidden.

How can I make the pictures appear?

BW Peter Bunde Hansen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enter the following line in the Immediate Window to make all pictures on the active sheet visible...

```
activesheet.pictures.visible = true
```

Hope this helps!